# MVC 5 Open View In New Window

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to open a view in a new browser window however, it's currently opening up in a new tab. I've tried Chrome, Edge and Explorer yet I'm not sure what it is. This is my razor code so far:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilePost", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", target = "_blank" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="inputFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible purely in HTML anymore, in any of the latest browsers, because of its rampant misuse in the past.

[However, you can use JavaScript to accomplish this effect.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Ohhh, what would you recommend the best way is to open a new window?

Comment: @JohnTheWizard I updated my answer with a link to MDN's page for the related javascript, in case you missed it.